# how to replace a value of a number in a text file with another using fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I have a text file in which I want to replace my temperature values. The position of this numbers are random in the text and looks like:

'xdd "D:\Data\Ioana\DH1_Short_slow\DH1_360_2.xye" xye_format
  local !Temperature 360

... (more text)

```
prm    bnonh360  1.66237`_0.41541
prm bh360 = 1.2 * bnonh360;
site Na1 x ref_flag -0.11868`_0.00258 y ref_flag  0.51229`_0.00446 z ref_flag  0.00330`_0.00107 occ Na 1 beq = bnonh360;
```

...(more text)

```
Out_CIF_STR_Uiso("D:\Data\Ioana\DH1_Short_slow\DH1_360.cif")
Out_Profile("D:\Data\Ioana\DH1_Short_slow\DH1_360_plot.pro")
Out_Tick("D:\Data\Ioana\DH1_Short_slow\DH1_360_plot.tic") '
```

More text means more text in the file. I want to replace 360 with 365 for instance.

I have tried something like

```
   do
     read(10,'(a)',iostat=iok) line1
     found = ( (index(line1,'360') /=0) )
     if (found) then
       write(*,*) '365'
      endif 
     if(line1 == '$') exit
     write(*,*) line1
     write(40,*,iostat=iok) line1
  enddo
```

But this just writes 365 in a next line where 360 is found.

Thanks

Comment: It'd probably be infinitely easier if you used [grepWIN](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) (regular expression tool for Windows) to replace `360` with `365`.

Comment: Or, you could use the Powershell: `cat file.txt | %{$_ -replace "365","360"} | Set-Content new.txt`.

Comment: You need to determine the substring containing the characters to replace,  then write to that substring, then output the entire string to a new file.

Comment: M.S.B thanks for your answer. Could you give me an example of how will you do that?

Answer (score -1):

you are discarding valuable information in the return value of index intrinsic.  to replace '360' to '365', which are of equal length, you can do

```
pos=index(line1,'360')
if(pos>0)   line1(pos:pos+2)='365'
```

or in general if you want to replace first occurrence of substring s1 with s2 in a string line, with s1 and s2 possibly having different length, and that they are padded with an indefinite number of spaces that you did not want to include in the replacement, you do

```
pos=index(line,trim(s1))
if(pos>0)  line=line(1:pos-1)//trim(s2)//line(pos+len_trim(s1):len_trim(line))
```

Should you want to include padding space in the replacement you can change the position offsets in the RHS substrings.   If you want to perform replacements for all occurrences you can enclose this in a while loop

This is of course under the assumption that the declared length of line is long enough to hold the new string.   However, note that **self-assignment is prohibited in FORTRAN77** so if that is what you are using, you will need different string variable to store the result.

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't answer the question. This explains how to edit a character variable in memory, the question is about changing the contents of a file.